# How to optimize two queries with union in my sql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have created the below query. but the below query taken lots of time to fetch result. i have added two queries and combined with union statement. how to optimize the below query in my sql. it consume much amount of time.

```
select count(*) as count 
        from(
        select id,createdUser,patientName,patientFirstName,patientLastName,tagnames 
        FROM vw_tagged_forms v1 where v1.tenant_id = 91 AND  
        CASE WHEN v1.patsiteId IS NOT  NULL  THEN v1.patsiteId IN 
        (151,2937,1450,1430,2746,1431,1472,1438,2431,1428) ELSE v1.patsiteId IS NULL  END group by 
        COALESCE(`message_grp_id`, `id`)
                 UNION 
        select 
         id,createdUser,patientName,patientFirstName,patientLastName,tagnames 
         FROM vw_tagged_forms_logs v2 where tenant_id = 91  AND CASE WHEN v2.patsiteId IS NOT  
         NULL  THEN v2.patsiteId IN (151,2937,1450,1430,2746,1431,1472,1431) ELSE v2.patsiteId IS 
         NULL  END) a
```

Comment: *THEN v1.patsiteId IN (151,2937,1450,1430,2746,1431,1472,**1438**,2431,1428)* in 1st subquery but *THEN v2.patsiteId IN (151,2937,1450,1430,2746,1431,1472,**14381**)* in 2nd. Is this correct or a typo?

Comment: The subqueries difference is only in the condition for `patsiteId`. This allows to combine yuour UNION into single query (with DISTINCT if subqueries output lists does not contain unique column).

Comment: it was typo. can you help me to solve optimizing this?

Comment: So, how to re-write my query? can i use left join instead of union?

Comment: Does `vw_tagged_forms_logs.id` is primary key?

Comment: yes. vw_tagged_forms_logs.id is primary key

Comment: @Akina , do you have any idea?

Comment: The query is logically incorrect. 1st subquery in your UNION performs incomplete GROUP BY which results in indefinite values selection for each separate group. So your total query is not deterministic (may produce different outputs on the same source data in two separate querings) - hence it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Akina , did you delete your answer?

Comment: Of course, I does take into acccount that the tablenames differs.

Comment: yes. the table name is different. So can you give solution for two different table?

Comment: I have explained why your query is not correct. It is illogical. And taking into account the processing after incomplete GROUP BY the whole query produces indefinite result which makes no sense. You must completely rewrite your query - it **must be deterministic**. And only after this you may think about the optimization.

Comment: ```COALESCE(`message_grp_id`, `id`)``` expression should be a column expression in the output list of 1st subquery. All another columns in this list must be wrapped with some aggregate function. This will make 1st subquery deterministic. The output list of 2nd subquery must be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplification:**  I think that

```
CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL
     THEN x IN (...)
     ELSE x IS NULL
     END
```

can be simplified to either of these:

```
x IN (...) OR x IS NULL
```

or

```
COALESCE(x IN (...), TRUE)
```

**Bug?** (The `IN` lists are not the same; was this an oversight?)

**INDEX (for performance):** Add this composite index, with the columns in the order given:

```
INDEX(tenant_id, patsiteId)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

**DISTINCT, id, etc:**

Are the `id` values different for the two tables?  If they are `AUTO_INCREMENT` and the rows were independently `INSERTed`, I would expect them to be different.  If, on the other hand, you copy a row from `v1` to `v2`, then I would expect the ids to match.

That leads to the question of "what are you counting"?  If the ids are expected to match, then do only `SELECT id`.  If they they were independently generated, then leave `id` out of the `SELECTs`; keep the other 5 columns.